# Почему не работает switch в C?

Tags: c, кодировка, switch

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,".1251");
char c;
printf("\nВведите первую букву:");
scanf("%c", &c); // ввести букву
switch (c) // заголовок оператора выбора
 {
 case 'а':
 case 'А':
     printf("\nАнтилопа"); break;
 case 'б':
 case 'Б':
     printf("\nБарсук"); break;
 case 'в':
 case 'В':
     printf("\nВолк"); break;
 default: printf("\nНе знаю я таких!");// по умолчанию
 }
getch();
}
```

"Не знаю я таких" выдаёт всегда

Comment: А что за буква при этом вводится? Добавьте printf для введенной буквы, скорее всего проблема в этом.

Comment: Для компиляции под линуксом, например, источник проблемы очевиден: кириллические буквы тупо не влазят в char. Об этом даже компилятор при компиляции предупреждает.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, зависит от кодировки.

Comment: @Олег Остапчук и главное, не забывайте о break!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировка консоли cp866. Соответственно и символьные литералы тоже должны быть в кодировке cp866.

Comment: В-общем, что сделать, чтоб и кириллица была и чтоб switch работал, не подскажете?

Comment: В CodeBlocks... Потому что вот, к примеру, есть программы специальные, но для другой IDE: http://kpolyakov.spb.ru/school/c/faq.htm

Comment: Про CodeBlocks ничего не могу вам подсказать, не пользовался им. В GCC вопрос решается указанием кодировок исходного и исполняемого файла - `gcc -finput-charset=utf-8 -fexec-charset=cp866 test.c`

Comment: Это где-то в настройках IDE указывается?

Comment: Скорее всего где-то в настройках IDE это должно быть, но мне это неизвестно. Я либо запускаю gcc вручную, либо с помощью make.

Answer (score 1):

> Кодировка консоли cp866.

Кодировка консоли здесь вторична. В какой кодировке набрана сама программа? Если:

- программа - cp1251
- консоль - 866

то очевидно. что они друг друга не понимают. Нужна функция перекодирования. Для линуха я знаю, для виндовоза - ищите сами.

Answer (score 0):

Проверочное выражение в круглых скобках внутри switch должно иметь целочисленное значение (включая тип `char`). Метки `case` должны быть константами целочисленного типа (в том числе `char`) или целочисленными константными выражениями (выражениями, которые содержат только целочисленные константы). Указывать для метки `case` переменную не допускается.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <locale.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char ch;
    printf("(int)'ё'=%d\n",(int)'ё');//ANSI C
    printf("Введите букву кириллицы. '0'- ноль для завершения.\n") ;
    while (scanf(" %c",&ch)==1&&ch!='0')
    {
      switch (ch)
        {
        case ((char)-32):// а
            printf("aкула\n");
            break;
        case ((char)-31)://б
        printf("баран\n");
        break;
    case ((char)-30)://в
        printf("выдра\n");
        break;
    case ((char)-29)://г
        printf("горностай\n");
        break;
    case ((char)-28)://д
        printf("дельфин\n");
        break;
    case ((char)-27)://е
        printf ("енот \n");
        break;
    case ((char)-72)://ё
        printf ("ёж \n");
        break;
    default :
        printf("Boпpoc озадачил!\n");
    } /* конец оператора выбора */
} /* конец цикла while */
printf ("До свидания.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как интересно, а с моей кодировкой системы это отработает? `現在のコード ページ: 932` ?

Comment: Это только с ansi c

Comment: Японские кажись. Ну через printf( ) в моём коде подставь русскую букву если выведет число просто вбей в case нужное значение и всё. Я специально для этого "ё" туда всунул.

Comment: Да мне это не особо то и нужно, это просто уточнение к ответу, что это не сработает если в системе нет поддержки кодировки `CP 1251`.

Comment: ansi не единственная кодировка кажись в которой представлена кириллица. Но какие именно я не в курсе. wchar_t  wctype.h не зависит от кодировок но его значения слишком большие.  case  не дотягивается до них.  Можно ещё лоб поморщить может и есть выход.

Comment: На Android switch case нормально работает с символами кириллицы.